# different output of model.fit (after loading model no training) and model.predict in keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

the def get_vgg_twoeyes() is the definition of my model. 
I have loaded a pretrained model,which is trained on the same computer,then I want to fine-tune the model. Before retrain the model, I set the model.trainable false that assure the weights of model are fixed. Before my training, the weights are the same to the saved weights. I found the output of model.fit is different from the output of model.predict.
As I assume that the model.fit with same weights as model.predict should output the same result because model.trainable is false that means the model.fit behave the model.predict.

def get_vgg_twoeyes(optimizer='adam', model_type='VGG16',fc1_size=1024, 
                    fc2_size=512, fc3_size=256):

```
kern_init = initializers.glorot_normal()
img_input = Input(shape=(36, 60, 3), name='img_input')
headpose_input = Input(shape=(2,), name='headpose_input')

# create the base pre-trained model
if model_type == 'VGG19':
    base_model = VGG19(input_tensor=img_input, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
elif model_type == 'VGG16':
    base_model = VGG16(input_tensor=img_input, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
else:
    raise Exception('Unknown model type in get_vgg_twoeyes')

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(fc1_size, kernel_initializer=kern_init)(x)
x = concatenate([x, headpose_input])
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)

x = Dense(fc2_size, kernel_initializer=kern_init)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)

gaze_predictions = Dense(2, kernel_initializer=kern_init, name='pred_gaze')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=[img_input, headpose_input], outputs=gaze_predictions)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=angle_loss, metrics=['accuracy', accuracy_angle])
return model

# fine-tune the model
models=load_model(model_path + "15Fold" + prefix + ''+str(i) + 
    suffix + ".h5",custom_objects={'accuracy_angle':accuracy_angle, 
     'angle_loss': angle_loss}))

model.trainable=False
adam = Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.95)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=angle_loss, metrics= ['accuracy', accuracy_angle]) 
model.fit({'img_input':cal_images,'headpose_input':cal_headposes},
cal_gazes,shuffle=False,batch_size=32,epochs=1,callbacks= 
  [losshistory()])

predgaze=model.predict({'img_input': cal_images, 'headpose_input': 
   cal_headposes},  batch_size=2,verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to probably compile the model again after setting `model.trainable=False`. Else, you can manually freeze the layers individually like

`for l in model.layers: 
    l.trainable=False`

Comment: I used the model.compile to compile the model again. And I have check the weights before and after the model.fit. The weights didn't change.

Comment: I think then possibly batch_norm is not being set to validation mode. Basically, batchnorm calculates batch average and variance at training time but running mean and variance at test time and thus leads to different output depending upon whether you are training or testing. To ensure you get the same output by using model.fit you may need to set trainable = False explicitly for all the layers. Also, you may want to read this https://blog.datumbox.com/the-batch-normalization-layer-of-keras-is-broken/

Comment: Thank you very much,the cause is Batch normalization layer. Although I get different output after set all layers trainable false, different output still remain. May this is related to whether it is training or testing as you say. But the outputs are close which are distant before setting batch normalization trainable false.